# Array fits comfortably within available RAM, but a memory error still occurs when calling numpy.take on it

Tags: numpy

I have three arrays of shape `(1029,1146,8,5)`. They are `H4`, `rowOffsets`, and `colOffsets`. H4 is float32 while the other two are int. Assuming 4 bytes per element array, `H4` has a cost of 188.7 MB.

My machine has 32 GB RAM total, with 18 currently available. I used `platform.architecture()` to verify that the Python interpreter is 64 bit, so that RAM ought to be available.

It seems like I'm nowhere near the memory limit, yet I get a memory error when I run the following:

```
shifted=np.take(H4,rowOffsets,0,mode='clip').
```

I further tested this by running the code up to the Take call with a much larger input of `(3000,3000,8,5)`. This consumed 7 times more memory yet also did not cause a memory error until the Take call.

So I figure I'm using Take wrong, there's a bug with it, or it consumes a massive amount of memory while executing. Can anyone help clarify what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multi-dimensional arguments `take` takes a full slice of all but the `axis` dimension for each entry in `indices`. Thus the way you use it the result would be `1029 * 1146**2 * 8**2 * 5**2 * itemsize` which is a lot and explains your memory problems.

You probably want to use `take_along_axis` instead.

Comment: "Which is a lot." You're not kidding.Thanks for the explanation.